# Animate and Finish Animate using jQuery

Tags: jquery

start button and Finish button does not work as i have given ids to both of them. i want to start animate and when i click Finish it should finish animate

```
<script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#start_Animate").click(function()
    {
        $("div").animate(2000);
    });
    $("#finish_Animate").click(function()
    {
        $("div").finish();
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="start_Animate">Start Animate</button>
<button id="finish_Animate">Stop Animate</button>
<div style="background-color:#900; width:400px; display:none; height:300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call animate, you should tell it what to do also, in this case you can use the simple `show(2000)` to display the element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#start_Animate").click(function() {
    //$("div").show(2000)
    $("div").animate({
      width: ["toggle", "swing"],
      height: ["toggle", "swing"]
    }, 2000, "linear");
  });
  $("#finish_Animate").click(function() {
    $("div").finish();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start_Animate">Start Animate</button>
<button id="finish_Animate">Stop Animate</button>
<div style="background-color:#900; width:400px; display:none; height:300px"></div>
```

Comment: Actully I want animate it when i click start button here --- $("#start_Animate").click(function() {
    $("div").show(2000)  <<< here i want animate(3000);
  });

Comment: I appreciate for your help. But my intension is to use animate function instead of show()

Comment: And Also tell me how can I build my logical skills as I am new to jQuery, if you want to tell me any ebook or any online tutorial will appreciate

Comment: thanx that is what i needed